# Basic Javascript only works on Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote some very basic javascript to show a div based on a users selection in a dropdown menu. For some reason this only works on firefox, not chrome, safari, or ie etc. Could someone point me in the right direction?

You can see the entire solution on jsfiddle here
http://jsfiddle.net/TR5a5/53/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".SelectSmallDog").change(function(){
        $( "select option:selected").each(function(){
            if($(this).attr("value")=="1SmallDog"){
                $(".box").hide();
                $(".1SmallDog").show();
            }
            if($(this).attr("value")=="2SmallDog"){
                $(".box").hide();
                $(".2SmallDog").show();
            }
            if($(this).attr("value")=="3SmallDog"){
                $(".box").hide();
                $(".3SmallDog").show();
            }
            if($(this).attr("value")=="4SmallDog"){
                $(".box").hide();
                $(".4SmallDog").show();
            }
            if($(this).attr("value")=="5SmallDog"){
                $(".box").hide();
                $(".5SmallDog").show();
            }
            if($(this).attr("value")=="6SmallDog"){
                $(".box").hide();
                $(".6SmallDog").show();
            }
            if($(this).attr("value")=="7SmallDog"){
                $(".box").hide();
                $(".7SmallDog").show();
            }
            if($(this).attr("value")=="8SmallDog"){
                $(".box").hide();
                $(".10SmallDog").show();
            }

            if($(this).attr("value")=="9SmallDog"){
                $(".box").hide();
                $(".9SmallDog").show();
            }
            if($(this).attr("value")=="10SmallDog"){
                $(".box").hide();
                $(".10SmallDog").show();
            }

            if($(this).attr("value")=="11SmallDog"){
                $(".box").hide();
                $(".11SmallDog").show();
            }
            if($(this).attr("value")=="12SmallDog"){
                $(".box").hide();
                $(".12SmallDog").show();
            }
            if($(this).attr("value")=="13SmallDog"){
                $(".box").hide();
                $(".13SmallDog").show();
            }
            if($(this).attr("value")=="14SmallDog"){
                $(".box").hide();
                $(".14SmallDog").show();
            }
            if($(this).attr("value")=="15SmallDog"){
                $(".box").hide();
                $(".15SmallDog").show();
            }
            if($(this).attr("value")=="16SmallDog"){
                $(".box").hide();
                $(".16SmallDog").show();
            }
            if($(this).attr("value")=="17SmallDog"){
                $(".box").hide();
                $(".17SmallDog").show();
            }
            if($(this).attr("value")=="18SmallDog"){
                $(".box").hide();
                $(".18SmallDog").show();
            }
            if($(this).attr("value")=="19SmallDog"){
                $(".box").hide();
                $(".19SmallDog").show();
            }
            if($(this).attr("value")=="20SmallDog"){
                $(".box").hide();
                $(".20SmallDog").show();
            }
            if($(this).attr("value")=="21SmallDog"){
                $(".box").hide();
                $(".21SmallDog").show();
            }
            if($(this).attr("value")=="22SmallDog"){
                $(".box").hide();
                $(".22SmallDog").show();
            }
            if($(this).attr("value")=="23SmallDog"){
                $(".box").hide();
                $(".23SmallDog").show();
            }
            if($(this).attr("value")=="24SmallDog"){
                $(".box").hide();
                $(".24SmallDog").show();
            }

            if($(this).attr("value")=="25SmallDog"){
                $(".box").hide();
                $(".25SmallDog").show();
            }

            if($(this).attr("value")=="ChooseSmallDog"){
                $(".box").hide();
                $(".ChooseSmallDog").show();
            }               

        });
    }).change();
});
```

Thanks so much

Comment: No issue in the code works perfectly just added the jquery in the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/yo7womb3/

Comment: What happens in Chrome? Any errors in the console? Some other, unexpected behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).attr("value")` is usually wrong, as the `value` *attribute* does not reflect the value of an input (strange but true). You want `this.value` or `$(this).val()` (or `$(this).prop("value")`) if you want the *current* value.

The `value` *attribute* reflects the `value` set in the markup, which is the *default value* of the input, not its current value. The `value` *property* of an input reflects its actual value. (There's also `defaultValue` property, which is directly linked to the `value` attribute, and not the current value of the `input`.)

Here's an example of how the `value` *attribute*, the `value` *property*, and the `defaultValue` *property* work:

```js
$("input[type=button]").on("click", function() {
  var $input = $("input[type=text]");
  show("<code>$input.val() = '" + $input.val() + "'");
  show("<code>$input.prop('value') = '" + $input.prop('value') + "'");
  show("<code>$input.attr('value') = '" + $input.attr('value') + "'");
  show("<code>$input.prop('defaultValue') = '" + $input.prop('defaultValue') + "'");
});
function show(msg) {
  $("<p>").html(msg).appendTo(document.body);
}
```

```html
<p>Type something in the input, and then click the button.</p>
<input type="text" value="default">
<input type="button" value="Click Me">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Also, OP has a drop down (single select) list, so there is no need for his use of $( "select option:selected") with an .each() loop. Just $(this).val() where `this` is the select element.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out the solution for the time being if any other newbies run into this issue

I needed to use

```
jQuery(function ($) {
```

not

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

Comment: This is not a generic solution. A "normal" include of jQuery results in the `$` and `jQuery` variables being aliases of the same function. The code shown in the question works in isolation in all browsers (the linked fiddle worked fine for me), so if this answer fixes the problem it's  because of other details not mentioned in the question.